Android resource tools TargetApi Doesn't Work?
I am getting the following error when building my Android app while compiling by syles.xml file:
Error: android:windowSplashScreenBackground requires API level 31 (current min is 30) [NewApi]

The error description is very good and states:
   Similarly, you can use tools:targetApi="11" in an XML file to indicate that
   the element will only be inflated in an adequate context.

I updated the xml file with:
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tool">
     ...
     <style name="AppTheme.Template.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item tools:targetApi="31" name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/evergreen</item>

Yet I still get:
<snip>/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:29: Error: android:windowSplashScreenBackground requires API level 31 (current min is 30) [NewApi]
        <item tools:targetApi="31" name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/evergreen</item>
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Do I have the syntax incorrect or is this simply not supported?

Adding tools:targetApi will only satisfy the android studio's linter.
To explain the error simply,the compiler is saying you are trying to use something which has been created from android api 31. It can not be used for android 30 because it does not exist in android 30.
You can try creating one extra styles.xml file with xml qualifier for android 31 and above.
This way you will have two styles.xml files :

one which is used for android 30
other which is used for android 31 & above.

then use android:windowSplashScreenBackground only in the one which support android 31 & above.
You may be required to find a alternative solution for android 30 though.
